# Is there a secure function in python that outputs a message ONLY after a certain time?

Tags: python

For example:

- Save a variable with message : "Hello World"
- Give a date that represents the date that the message can be opened in a message box
- Create an interface that you press a button and it will output the message if today's time is greater than the date I saved.

I tried using datetime.now() but anyone can manipulate/fake the system time.

What would you recommend me?

Comment: Anyone who can manipulate the system time can manipulate anything that the Python script tries to do.

Answer (score 1):

If you are worried about time-lock security, you will be better served with a more secure data transfer: simply don't write the message until the specified time!  Set up a `cron` job to run a short message-creation script at the specified time.